# Чтение и запись членов union

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer

Никак не могу найти однозначный ответ на следующий вопрос.

Сколько себя помню, `union`-ы всегда использовались не столько для поочередного хранения разных данных в одном месте, сколько для гибкого доступа к некоторым кускам этих самых данных. Иначе говоря, для записи данных одного типа и чтения данных другого типа.

Например:

```
typedef union u_color_pack
{
    uint8_t b[4];
    uint32_t raw;
} color_pack;

// …

uint8_t color_check(const uint32_t _raw)
{
    color_pack color;
    color.raw = _raw;
    if (color.b[0] == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    } 
    return 1;
}
```

`color_pack` позволяет работать с цветом как с сырыми данными типа `uint32_t` или же напрямую обращаться к отдельным байтам (цветам). Да, я понимаю, что приведенный код зависит от порядка байтов, но такой код обычно пишется с расчетом на строго определенный порядок байтов.

Так вот, проблема в том, что некоторые говорят, что нельзя читать из `union`-а данные типа `A`, если перед этим в `union` были записаны данные типа `B`.

Одни говорят, что такая ситуация является неопределенным поведением. Другие - что это поведение, определяемое реализацией.

Что по этой проблеме говорят стандарты `C` и `C++`? Отличается ли то, что они говорят?

Comment: С разрешает, а С++ - запрещает (хотя, например, в мануале к GCC написано, что он в виде исключения разрешает это даже в С++). Единственный частный случай, в котором это разрешено в С++, это когда и активный, и выбранный члены `union`а - [standard-layout типы](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/StandardLayoutType) с одинаковым набором полей в начале - тогда можно обращаться к любому из этих полей. За ссылками на стандарт лучше подождать кого-то вроде AnT. :)

Comment: порядка байтов в системе - чаще всего - define - опция записывается через `#ifdef else endif`, имеет смысл, только если вы пишите кросс-процессорное приложение, или какое-то кросс-платформенное с особыми платформами. Если вы пишите под винду или обычный линукс на x86/x64 и не планируете менять на CPU другой платформы -  то это не нужно учитывать.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, в каких частях стандартов это вообще искать?

Comment: Не знаю, по слову `union`?

Comment: Жду прихода `Ant`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача обращатся по одному адресу к данным и как к целой структуре и как к массиву байт - очень часто-встречаемая задача.

из комментариев от VTT, что б избежать UB следует делать так.

```
uint8_t color_check(const uint32_t _raw)
{
   uint_8_t * b = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(&raw)
   if (b[0] == 0)
   {
      return 0;
   } 
  return 1;
}
```

Не следует делать через

1. union - т.к. UB -оптимизатор предполагает что за одну "итерацию" юнион использует одну ветвь, и при включеном оптимизаторе нового поколения программа может отработать не верно.
2. Через каст без указания типа каста. `((char*)&_raw)[0]` - можно поймать UB.

Про  порядок байт - порядок байт может меняться, только если используются нестандартные платформы, т.е. если вы предполагаете, что код будет работать на платформах отличных от intel x86/x64-совместимых (или там AMD). Для ускорения вычислений - делают предопределение `#define` и назначают значение предпроцессору, например

```
#ifdef litte_indian
   // Прямой порядок
#else
   // Обратный порядок
#endif
```

Теперь касательно стандартов.

На счёт UB https://habr.com/ru/post/216189/ п 1.3.12

> Неопределенное поведение (undefined behavior)– поведение, которое
>   может возникать в результате использования ошибочных программных
>   конструкций или некорректных данных, на которые Международный Стандарт
>   не налагает никаких требований. Неопределенное поведение также может
>   возникать в ситуациях, не описанных в Стандарте явно.

На счёт использования union, стандарт `с` не оговаривает как правильно использовать юнион, а стандарт `c++` вам уже ответили VTT п 12.3

> В с++ union в любой момент времени может быть активно не более одного
>   поля. За исключением доступа к общей подструктуре standard-layout
>   объектов, доступ к неактивным полям является неопределенным
>   поведением. В общем случае для обращения к неактивному полю сначала
>   следует вручную вызвать деструктор активного поля, затем вызвать
>   placement new поля, которое требуется сделать активным.

Comment: *"Через каст без указания типа каста. `((char*)&_raw)[0]` - можно поймать UB."* А что, `char*` - не указание типа каста? UB тут не будет, C-style cast здесь работает как `reinterpret_cast`. *"Через memcpy, т.к. memcpy оптимизатор тоже оптимизирует - можно поймать UB."* - Оптимизатору не разрешается создавать UB там, где его не было, это нарушало бы as-if rule. Так что тут тоже без UB. Да и к тому же, метод с кастом работает только для `char`/`unsigned char` (для `uint8_t` тоже).

Comment: За memcpy - почитал, да, можно. За первое я на SO участвовал в вопросе где говорилось что так нельзя делать... сейчас поищу....

Answer (score 4):

В С++ в union в любой момент времени может быть активно не более одного поля. За исключением доступа к общей подструктуре standard-layout объектов, доступ к неактивным полям является неопределенным поведением. В общем случае для обращения к неактивному полю сначала следует вручную вызвать деструктор активного поля, затем вызвать placement new поля, которое требуется сделать активным.

> **12.3 Unions [class.union]**
>   **1** In a union, a non-static data member is active if its name refers to an object whose lifetime has begun and has not ended (6.8). At most one of the non-static data members of an object of union type can be active at any time, that is, the value of at most one of the non-static data members can be stored in a union at any time. [Note: One special guarantee is made in order to simplify the use of unions: If a standard-layout union
>   contains several standard-layout structs that share a common initial sequence (12.2), and if a non-static data member of an object of this standard-layout union type is active and is one of the standard-layout structs, it is permitted to inspect the common initial sequence of any of the standard-layout struct members; see 12.2. —end note ]

Comment: *вызвать деструктор активного поля* это как? т.е. для даного случая выше, как должен выглядеть код? Валидный ли код в вопросе, если нет, то как правильно записать приведеный код?

Comment: @nick_n_a  `color.raw.~uint32_t();` Код в вопросе невалидный, для доступа к `b` это поле сначала надо инициализировать, при этом инициализация поля `raw` теряет смысл и "гибкого доступа" тут не получается

Comment: Хотя по идее именно в этом случае деструктор можно не вызывать, раз тип - trivially-destructible.

Comment: Там можно или нельзя? Так деструктор должен очистить переменную? Тогда результат не тот... Может неопределенное поведение UB можно выключать опцией компилятора тогда когда это надо? Вот что делать имменно в таких случаях? Через ссылку - нельзя - UB, через union - нельзя - UB. Как делать в таких случаях?

Comment: @nick_n_a Единственный нормальный способ в С++, насколько я знаю - делать `memcpy` во временную переменную и надеяться, что компилятор уберет ее при оптимизации.

Comment: @nick_n_a Чтобы просто к байтам получить доступ? Для этого достаточно сделать `reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(&raw)`

Comment: Наверно... осталось это всё подшить в ответ:)