# Перевод в big-endian, проблемы с данными типа signed

Tags: c++

Прошу помощи со следующим вопросом.
Имеется бинарный файл, достаточно большой. Большая часть данных записаны в порядке от старшего байта к младшему. До некоторого момента у меня не возникало проблем, т.к. все данные были строго положительные. К слову использовал я библиотеку endian.h , и я почти уверен, что она стандартная. Приведу пример того, как я это делаю, основанный на моем коде:

```
string fileName = "NSS.AMAX.NK.D11171.S1811.E1941.B6812425.WI";
ifstream in(fileName.c_str(), ios::binary);
int32_t i4;

in.read((char *)&i4, 4);
cout << "latitude: " << htobe32(i4) << endl;
```

Примерно таким образом я и парсил файл, но вот незадача, htobe32 работает только с типом unsigned, что меня не устраивает. Т.к. некоторые числа, такие как широта и долгота в моем случае могут быть отрицательными. Так например перевод в big-endian на C# у меня выглядел так:

```
 if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
 {
 Array.Reverse(item);
 Console.Write(BitConverter.ToInt32(item, 0));
 }
```

Тут item - это массив байтов byte[]. И работал код с любым типом int. Собственно в случае, когда на C# я получал логичное -542112, то на плюсах несуразное 4294425184. Это запись записана как градусы*(10^4). То есть грубо говоря я получаю -54,2112 градуса. Вот такой же результат мне бы хотелось видеть в С++. Я не очень умный и потому очень прошу подробно объяснить ответ. Спасибо :-)

Comment: Если проблема **только** в порядке байт - то можно просто выполнить приведение типа. Хуже, если не стыкуется [представление отрицательных чисел](https://inf1.info/additionalcode) - тогда нужны дополнительные действия...

Comment: Я несколько дней не мог найти ответ, но спустя минуту после жеста отчаяния в виде вопроса все-таки нашел его, даже немного стыдно. К слову приведение типов результата не дало.

Comment: Ну, тогда поделитесь :)

Answer (score 0):

Может быть кому-нибудь пригодится, оказалось все просто. Ответ нашел на форуме линуксоедов от пользователя arsi 2009г. Ответ был написан для unsigned типа, но переделать метод было проще простого.

```
int32_t htobe32s(int32_t x)
{
    union {
        int32_t u32;
        int8_t v[4];
    } ret;
    ret.v[0] = (uint8_t)(x >> 24);
    ret.v[1] = (uint8_t)(x >> 16);
    ret.v[2] = (uint8_t)(x >> 8);
    ret.v[3] = (uint8_t)x;
    return ret.u32;
}
```

Comment: А что, просто `int32_t htobe32s(int32_t x) {return htobe32(x);}` не работает?

Comment: К сожалению нет, в этом я уверен. Так как на входе у меня всегда был int32_t. htobe32 приводит int32_t к uint32_t . Я также пробовал явное преобразование и эффект был нулевым.

Comment: А ведь должно работать, странно. Смотрите, тут работает: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/430fae6e3df0a5c9

Comment: Этот фрагмент имеет Неопределенное Поведение так как происходит обращение к неактивному полю union.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , да, но если изменить код на http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8912dfa3ab37068 , т.е. воспользоваться стандартом, то результат будет таким же, как и с htobe32s при выводе. Однако в моем случае это не работает. Может ли бы это быть особенностью системы или компилятора? Пользуюсь Linux Mint 19.1 , компилятор gcc.

Comment: @VTT , я впервые столкнулся с union и насколько могу судить, он позволяет представить один и тот же результат сразу в нескольких типах, т.е. записанный результат в int8_t[4] также будет представлен и в int32_t. Мне понятна логика этой части кода, которую пытался донести автор, или я неправильно его понял?

Comment: "*позволяет представить один и тот же результат сразу в нескольких типах*" - нет, union такого не позволяет, это скорее частый паттерн его неправильного использования. см [Чтение и запись членов union](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/952590/Чтение-и-запись-членов-union/952596#952596)

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно воспользоваться boost.endian:

```
#include <boost/endian/arithmetic.hpp>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    ::std::int32_t const native{123456789};
    ::std::int32_t const big_endian{::boost::endian::native_to_big(native)};
    ::std::printf("Native    %08x\nBigEndian %08x\n", native, big_endian);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я не пользовался раннее boost'ом. Но Ваш код работает в онлайн, обязательно опробую его на целевой машине, благодарю за ответ!