# прямое приведение типа из std::string в std::wstring

Tags: c++

требуется привести содержимое string которое содержит символы кодировки utf16be к wstring. как можно это реализовать в mvs19(windows)?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string in{ 0x00, 0x68, 0x00, 0x65, 0x00, 0x6C, 0x00, 0x6C, 0x00, 0x6F,0x00, 0x0D, 0x00, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x77, 0x00, 0x6F, 0x00, 0x72, 0x00, 0x6C, 0x00, 0x64 };
    cout << in.size() << endl;
    
    wstring target;
    cout << target.size() << endl;
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Для каждого символа выполнить https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/970808/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2-big-endian-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b0-signed/970994#970994