# Какие могут быть аналоги у функций be64toh и htobe64 для windows?

Tags: c++, linux, winapi

В linux есть функции:

```
uint64_t be64toh(uint64_t big64);
uint64_t htobe64(uint64_t host64);
```

определённые в заголовочнике include <sys/endian.h>, какие могут быть аналоги для windows?

Comment: htonl / ntohl ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/970808/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2-big-endian-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b0-signed/970994#970994